# Extracting list of patterns which are output of another command

Tags: shell, command-line, text-processing, grep, process-substitution

I can extract list of patterns using following command,

```
fgrep -A 1 -f patternlist.txt filename.fasta
```

but, is there a way I can extract without creating another file (patternlist.txt in this case) from other command's output?

Such as:

```
cut -d "      "  Cell_cycle.txt -f 1 | grep ...???... filename.fasta
```

EDIT:

The Cell_cycle.txt looks like this:

```
$ cat Cell_cycle_Kegg_pathway
ctg2977_3.g207.t1   K06626
P05_Ctg654_12.g311.t2   K03094
P06_Ctg710_7.g346.t1    K05868
```

i want to take the first column and extract those sequences from fasta file.

EDIT 2:

I have list of sequences in a `UniqueSeq_28Dec2014.fasta`

```
>ctg1474_1.g69.t1 (first line)
atgaaatgttggtgcagcgccctggcacttctcc...... (second line)
>ctg1475_1.g70.t1 (third line)
atgaaattgcagcgccctggcacttctcctgcag...... (fourth line)
```

I want to print the first two sequences (from lines 1 to 4). However, I do not want to use `head -4 UniqueSeq_28Dec2014.fasta` which can also give my output, but I want it using process substitution.

I tried the following command but does not seem to work. I just see 4 empty lines.

```
grep -A 1 -Ff <(grep '>' UniqueSeq_28Dec2014.fasta |head -4) UniqueSeq_28Dec2014.fasta
```

Comment: Yes you can. Do you mind letting us know what the pattern is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use process substitution `<()`:

```
fgrep -A 1 -f <(cut -d " " -f 1 Cell_cycle.txt)  filename.fasta
```

Comment: Hi was trying to implement your answer in other instance. The following does not give me output: `grep -A 1 -Ff <(grep '>' UniqueSeq_28Dec2014.fasta |head -4) UniqueSeq_28Dec2014.fasta` I just wanted to extract only top 4 sequences this way.

Comment: What is the content of `UniqueSeq_28Dec2014.fasta`?

Comment: It is sequence file in fasta format. First line contains a header with ">" in the beginning and second line contains a sequence of letters (and file contains many headers and sequences).

Comment: @PrakkiRama please edit your question and give a short sample of the file which don't work. I cannot reproduce the problem from your description.

Comment: Hi Jimmij. Please see my Edit2.

Comment: @PrakkiRama your command works fine for me - it just reproduce the file, whole four lines. You don't even need `head -4`, just `grep -A 1 -Ff <(grep '>' UniqueSeq_28Dec2014.fasta) UniqueSeq_28Dec2014.fasta` is enough in this example. If it doesn't work test in steps, so first what `grep '>' UniqueSeq_28Dec2014.fasta` returns. It should be two lines: first and third. It is also wise idea to pass `--colour=auto` in order to see what exactly matches, in this case `>` at the beginning of the line should be highlighted.

Comment: Yes. You seem to be correct. Thank you Jimmj.

Answer (score 1):

Also this(for slightly shorter and more readability):

```
grep -Ff <(awk '{print $1}' Cell_cycle.txt) filename.fasta
```